# Unable to decode data from csv file (utf-8), file has been opened through a url

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, utf-8

I am trying to extract a csv file from an email (link) and convert that to a dictionary. The link which I have downloads the file as soon as you click it. Here's the code I am trying

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(<link_to_download_file>)
for l in response.readlines():
    #print(l)
    print(l.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

I am trying to utilize the csv module with the above mentioned snippet:

```
lines = [l.decode('utf-8') for l in response.readlines()]
cr = csv.reader(lines)

for row in cr:
    print(row)
```

This is what `l` prints:
`` b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x00\x08\x00c\x94mU\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00xl/theme/theme1.xml\xedYM\x8f\xdb6\x1a\xbe\xef\xaf xOl\xcfx&3B\x94"\xf6\xd8\xc9n2\xed`\xc6I\x91\xe3k\x89\x96\x98\xa1H\x81\xa4g\xc6\xb7"=.\xb0@\xd1\x0f\xf4R\xa0\xb7\x1e\x16\xdb\x06h\x80^\xb2\xbf&\xbbY\xecf\x81\xfc\x85\x05IQ\x16m9\x99|\x14\xc5\xa2\x99CbI\xcf\xf3~\xbf/I\xe9\xfaG\x17\x05CgD**x\x8c{W\xbb\x18\x11\x9e\x88\x94\xf2,\xc6\xf7&\xe3+{\x18)\r<\x05&8\x89\xf1\x82(\xfc\xd1\x8d?\\\x87H\xe7\xa4 \xe8\xa2`\\E\x10\xe3\\\xeb2\xeatT\x92\x93\x02\xd4UQ\x12~Q\xb0\x99\x90\x05huU\xc8\xac\x93J8\xa7<+Xg\xab\xdb\xdd\xed\x14@9F\x1c\n' ``

And the decoded string I get is:
`` <♣&8(э?\H `\E►\2tT☻UQ↕~Q♣huUȬJ8<+Xg¶@9F∟2`IkHgƷ"=.@R▲▬♠h^&Yf♣IQ▬m9|¶ŢCbI~/IG↨♣CgD**x{W↑◄,&+{↑) ``

I am assuming maybe `utf-8` is the wrong encoding?

Thank you for your time...

Trying to use requests module instead of urllib:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(link)

    decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')

    cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
    my_list = list(cr)
    for row in my_list:
        print(row)
```

Comment: The response is compressed. Use a smarter module like `requests`

Comment: @MarkTolonen 
getting: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 11: invalid start byte`

Please see updates in the question

Comment: The file is not in text format, so it cannot be processed by the csv module. You should know whether it is compressed (then decompress it) or in a binary format. **I** cannot know that...

Comment: @musical_ant Provide the link. Make a [mcve]. The data is compressed but the requests module should detect the content type and decompress assuming the content type is declared correctly. You can do it manually probably with `gzip.decompress`

Comment: The [file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) 
 `b'PK\x03\x04'` shows a zip file format and formats based on it…

Comment: Tried passing the data through `ZipFile` but it isn't the complete data.  Need the actual link if the OP wants more help.